# What does "unresolved implicit call to super constructor" mean in Dart Language?

Tags: class, inheritance, dart

How come this example:

```dart
import "dart:html";

class SubMenuElement extends DivElement {

    SubMenuElement() {
        print("my element created");
    }

}
```

Gives the error:

```
Internal error: 'file.dart': error: line x pos y: unresolved implicit call to super constructor 'DivElement()'
    SubMenuElement() {
                  ^
```

What does the error message mean and how would a working example be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a subclass of DivElement as follows:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

class MyDiv extends DivElement {
  factory MyDiv() => new Element.tag('div', 'my-div');
  MyDiv.created() : super.created();
}
```

The factory constructor is not required, but it is convenient if you want to construct instances imperatively.

You must then register your custom element with a document before you can instantiate it:

```dart
main() {
  document.register('my-div', MyDiv, extendsTag: 'div');
  document.body.append(new MyDiv()..text = 'Hello');
}
```

The above will work in Dartium, or any browser that natively implements the Custom Elements specification (Chrome 33+ for example).  To run in another browser, you will need to add the custom element polyfill.  You can add this to your pubspec:

```dart
dependencies:
  custom_element: '>=0.9.0'
  ...
```

And after running `pub get` you can add the polyfill script to your html:

```dart
<body>    
  <script src="packages/custom_element/custom-elements.min.js"></script>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: What do you think is the advantage of your solution vs. using polymer?

I guess if you want to add it declaratively you also have to use `<div is='my-div>...</div>'` like in polymer?

Comment: The custom element polyfill _is_ part of polymer.  But custom elements are becoming part of the standard web platform, and Chromium / Dartium has implemented the specification so you may not need a polyfill depending on your use case.  You can use also `<my-div>Ahoy!</my-div>` declaratively, go ahead and add it to the html in the example and you'll see it works :)

Answer (score 3):

DivElement doesn't have a default constructor.
You need to add a named constructor and a call to the named constructor on super.

```dart
SubMenuElement.created() : super.created();
```

If you derive a DOM element you should add `with Polymer`

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

class SubMenuElement extends DivElement with Polymer {
  SubMenuElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

You haven't stated that you want to create a Polymer element but you can use custom elements only with Polymer, so I assumed you do.

Comment: Doesn't work. Does it work for you? If so, do you mind sharing the code.

Comment: I am not using polymer though.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to use custom classed derived from DOM element classes.

Comment: You need browser support (or at least polyfill) for custom elements and Polymer is the only technology supported by Dart (There is also X-Tags from Firefox)

Comment: Creating a sub-class of DivElement, is that really a custom element? I just want to create a sub-class for convenient reasons, so I can add things in the constructor.

Comment: DivElement is not a Dart class. It's only a mapping to a Browser native class. This leads to limitations. I tried as I suggested above and DartEditor doesn't show a warning anymore but Dartium crashes when I run the app. The doc on the `DivElement.created()` constructor also states that `the constructor is instantiated by the DOM when a custom element has been created` so it's not intended to be called by user code.

Comment: As stated, you can only extend elements with Polymer and custom elements.

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that the default constructor `DivElement()` doesn't exist. This constructor is implicitly called because you didn't specify another constructor to be called.

That being said, DivElement can't be subclassed directly. But you can simulate that behaviour by implementing DivElement instead of extending it and delegating every call:

```dart
class MyDivElement implements DivElement {

  DivElement _delegate;

  MyDivElement() {
    _delegate = new DivElement();
    // whatever else should happen in your constructor
  }

  // For best performance, every member SHOULD be implemented explicitly.
  String get text => _delegate.text;
  Node get parentNode => _delegate.parentNode;
  ShadowRoot get shadowRoot => _delegate.shadowRoot;

  // But DivElement has a lot of members.
  // Unused or rarely used members could also be delegated with reflection.
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => reflect(_delegate).delegate(invocation);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It reminded me that I have to use the "implements", rather than "extends" keyword in what I've been thinking of as a subclass. I'm just learning Dart and am still looking forward to the day when the difference dawns on me :-)